# @font-face no funciona en Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

@font-face no funciona en Firefox y si en el resto de navegadores. He estado buscado preguntas pasadas y no encuentro la solución. Estoy trabajando en local.

Tengo las fuentes descargadas y las rutas están bien. La consola no marca nada.

Este es mi @font-face:

@font-face
{
font-family: OpenSemiBold;
src: url(../fuentes/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf) format('truetype'),
     url(../fuentes/OpenSans-SemiBold.woff) format('woff'),
     url(../fuentes/OpenSans-SemiBold.otf) format('opentype'),
     url(../fuentes/OpenSans-SemiBold.eot) format('embedded-opentype'),
     url(../fuentes/OpenSans-SemiBold.svg) format('svg'),
     url(../fuentes/OpenSans-SemiBold.woff2) format('woff2');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}

¿Que se me pasa?
Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704578/5587982), o bien [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542939/5587982) donde se recomienda poner comillas en las urls, algo así: `src: url('../fuentes/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'),`

Comment: Lo he solucionado con la respuesta del primer enlace. La modificación en mi about:config soluciona el problema solamente para mi local? Que ocurrirá cuando lo suba al servidor? Dependerá de cada persona y su configuración personal de firefox? o por el contrario no debería fallar independientemente del about:config ? Gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: Supongo que en en un contexto web no vas a obligar a cada usuario a descargar los archivos de fuentes, que los vas a brindar desde un sito web accesible a todos y en esos casos creo que no hay problema. El problema viene cuando los archivos están en local, me parece.

Comment: Para salir de dudas, vuelve a dejar la configuración como al principio, cuando fallaba, y coloca fuentes que estén en un sitio web, el tuyo o su sitio oficial.

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona de forma normal. Gracias por tu ayuda @A.Cedano